# left join in mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb

Below Query, we are using for fetching the data, how to convert this to as left join Query.
so if id column does not exist in a user_content table the value of count would be 0.

```
db.contents.aggregate([ 
    { "$lookup" : { 
          "from" : "user_content" , 
          "localField" : "_id" , 
          "foreignField" : "contentId" , 
          "as" : "user_content"}
    } , 
    { "$unwind" : { 
          "path" : "$user_content" , 
          "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true}
    } , 
    { "$match" : { "user_content.liked" : true}} , 
    { "$group" : { 
          "_id" : "$_id" , 
          "popularity" : { 
              "$first" : "$popularity"} , 
              "user_content" : { "$push" : "$user_content"}
          }
    } , 
    { "$project" : { 
          "popularity" : 1 , 
          "count" : { "$size" : [ "$user_content"]}}
    } , 
    { "$skip" : 0} , 
    { "$limit" : 1000000}
]);
```

Comment: You don't need to unwind, match and group. You can use `$filter` instead. Something like `db.contents.aggregate([ 
    { "$lookup" : { 
          "from" : "user_content" , 
          "localField" : "_id" , 
          "foreignField" : "contentId" , 
          "as" : "user_content"}
    }, 
    { "$project" : { 
          "popularity" : 1 , 
          "count" : { "$size" : {
            $filter: {
               input: "$user_content",
               cond: "$$this.liked"
            }
         }}
    }} , 
    { "$skip" : 0} , 
    { "$limit" : 1000000}
]);`

Comment: @Veeram Thanks. some small changed done:-   db.contents.aggregate([ { "$lookup" : { "from" : "user_content" , "localField" : "_id" , "foreignField" : "contentId" , "as" : "user_content"}} , { "$project" : { "popularity" : 1 , "count" : { "$size" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$user_content" , "as" : "uc" , "cond" : { "$eq" : [ "$$uc.liked" , true]}}}}}} , { "$skip" : 0} , { "$limit" : 1000000}]);